# 'System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject' is defined in an assembly

Tags: asp.net

I have created a service and when calling it and executing it getting the following error.Anybody tell me what is this error

> The type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

**I have used System.Runtime.Serialization in my project.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added the System.Runtime.Serialization in the main file and the error is been removed.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved by following procedure.

In **Reference** section of Project (i.e, In solution) add "**System.Runtime.Serialization**"

and Add "***using System.Runtime.Serialization;***" before namespace.

[image: Related Image is attached here]